# Html -- display elements when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a following html page. Here my requirement is that :---
1> when top vegetable button is pressed then 6 vegetables are shown.
2> When top animal button is pressed then 20 animals are shown.
3> When topautomobile button is pressed then 26 cars are shown.

I am posting the basic layout. What i am thinking is that add 26 elements (as maximum number of elements in div id="center" can be 26 not more than this) 
in the div "center". And hide the divs & change images & the description as per the button pressed.

Is it the right way. Please suggest how to achieve this ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
<title>My item list </title>
<style>
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}
.input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
}
.imgtxt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:15px;
}
#images {
    background-color: grey;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableCenter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#center {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body >
    <div id="images" class="scrollable">
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTBRnn9Aqx74JvKyJ7Z5ydbXXuj8cIDVuOdJZUxb02Q2LWfJGP" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">vegitable</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPsZfek4J5rZKHyPdgWu7qq9WJJzlpSSwCmUAFQflwLJqWxk_5sfy7r0mJ" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Animals</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhxj6l2Y_6ZiqXnY6fx-nLUgVzMMkdAndmMSTyJR31T15Itl2FZBAqlaSa" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Automobile</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center" class="scrollableCenter">
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMPmp8aVaovrd3AGj1_hL_GEXX1M4DJ-TTMJ34Vr622XeY_usu" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">brinjal</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Cauliflower.JPG" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">cauliflower</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJgt4i9ph9uQsS3JV940PBg-kwN1kkrKbC6FLYI6UhbxucEb91" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">tomato</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-mwuxaqQeHXjoZzPUoee9Rvg8Jq-eCvo8H0EgEtapjfr6U4E3" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ladyfinger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRxXUO2stKHLyET_rXpxOuLp67qc1IzlBcJGke5jYoGPeRZpnO" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">radish</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2zCeG621TSX1YmcsT9DPLaQJkdVwdYk_n-eWECCa8NTtXR0LFeQ" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ginger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fotter">List of Items</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is that is? [What Else Have You Tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: I have tried how to hide a div .. but just want to confirm what will be the right way to do this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest adding a class .vegatable , .car , .animal to seperate divs that cointains your images, and simply doing show() / hide() on thme. This will require jQuery but keeps things really simple.

```
$('.animal').show();  // this will show all divs that have animal class set
$('.vegetable').hide();  // this will hide all divs that have vegetable class set
$('.car').hide();  // this will hide all divs that have car class set
```

Here is jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/TbBgA/2/

Comment: i have one question that .. if suppose there are about 20 div elements horizontally eg animal, plants, human organs, vegetable , automobile .. etc .... and per element there are about 15 div items ... so then also  your answer is a good choice ... ? will it not cause overloading of webpage .. ?

Comment: Also if a div element is hidden then is it possible to change the image or text of the hidden element ... ?

Comment: @Katoch I think this should not be a problem even with 20 categories as I assume they are. If there would be any issues with larger number of them just put a comment here and then we will think. Yes you can freely change hidden elements as they are still there but just not displayed.

Comment: at present jquery task is hardcoded for divs to show or hide

Comment: .... is it possible to write a generic function showclass() to do the jquery task ... we have stored the class to hide or show in an array .. var area_id = [
    "animal" , "vegetable", "car "
]; now decision should be made from this array which class to show or hide .. example we will call this generic function this way .... when button for class auto is clicked.. onclick="showclass('car')" .... when button for class veg is clicked.. onclick="showclass('vegetable')" .. .... when button for class animal is clicked.. onclick="showclass('animal')" .....

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JG9n8/2/)

### Basically You woud want add 3 more div for ease i used your already existing div with id center and 2 more center1 center2 respectively

### Change Html Content to this

```
<div id="images1" class="scrollable">
        <div class="input">
            <input id="imgtxtV" type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTBRnn9Aqx74JvKyJ7Z5ydbXXuj8cIDVuOdJZUxb02Q2LWfJGP" onclick="alert('clicked')" title="Room one" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">vegitable</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input id="imgtxtA" type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQPsZfek4J5rZKHyPdgWu7qq9WJJzlpSSwCmUAFQflwLJqWxk_5sfy7r0mJ" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Animals</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input id="imgtxtAUTo" type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRhxj6l2Y_6ZiqXnY6fx-nLUgVzMMkdAndmMSTyJR31T15Itl2FZBAqlaSa" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Automobile</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

### Jquery script

```
$('#imgtxtV').click(function(){
    alert("clicked vegitables");

    $("#center").css("display", "block");
     $("#center1").css("display", "none");
     $("#center2").css("display", "none");
    }
);
$('#imgtxtA').click(function(){
    alert("clicked Animals");

    $("#center").css("display", "none");
     $("#center1").css("display", "block");
     $("#center2").css("display", "none");
    }
);
$('#imgtxtAUTo').click(function(){
    alert("clicked AutoMobiles");

    $("#center").css("display", "none");
     $("#center1").css("display", "none");
     $("#center2").css("display", "block");
    }
);
```